# How to update multiple Columns in a Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

**Updated with solution here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802973/12322995

Need help in implementing the below sql query in Spark Scala

```
Update testScores
SET score1 = a.score1,
    source1 = 'FoundOnline',
    score2 = a.score2,
    source2 = 'FoundOnline',
    score3 = a.score3,
    source3 = 'FoundOnline'
FROM
(select * from tempScores) a
WHERE testScores.Source1 != 'missing'
and a.score1 > 0
```

Below is what I have tried and stuck because got confused how to update both scores and sources columns with same conditions

I have two dataframes that reflect the data of two tables in the query

`testScoresDF`, `tempScoresDF`

```
val newResults =  testScoresDF.as("test").join(tempScoresDF.as("temp"), Seq("id","products"), "left")
.withColumn("temp_score1",
        when($"temp.score1".gt(0) and($"test.Souce1".notEqual("real")), $"temp.Score1")
          .otherwise($"test.Score1"))
.withColumn("temp_score2",
        when($"temp.score1".gt(0) and($"test.Souce1".notEqual("real")), $"temp.Score2")
          .otherwise($"test.Score2"))
.withColumn("temp_score3",
        when($"temp.score1".gt(0) and($"test.Souce1".notEqual("real")), $"temp.Score3")
          .otherwise($"test.Score3"))
```

Here is schema for both the tables. id and products are used to join

```
testScores
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- products: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score1: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score2: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score3: float (nullable = true)
 |-- source1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source3: string (nullable = true)
```

```
tempScores
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- products: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score1: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score2: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score3: float (nullable = true)
```

OutputSchema should be same as testScores schema with updated values.

```
Output
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- products: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score1: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score2: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score3: float (nullable = true)
 |-- source1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source3: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some sample input and output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using withColumn can work but it will have a lot of repeated code and conditions.

So here's the solution that works better when required to `Update` a `DataFrame`

Using `fold or foldLeft or foldRight` should work in any case where a list of columns requires some updates. [fold vs foldLeft vs foldRight](https://commitlogs.com/2016/09/10/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright/)

Briefly - if there is a list with columns or values, `fold - will read one index at a time randomly`, `foldLeft - will read the list of values beginning from left to right`, `foldRight - is opposite to foldLeft.Reads from Right to Left`

Solution:

1). First left join the two dataframes. Left join because we need to update only values that satisfies the condition or else leave them as it is.

2). `cols: List[String]` has a list of columns to be updated. Here `List("score1", "score2", "score3","Source1","Source2","Source3")`

3). foldLeft takes the joinedDF and list of columns to be updated and iterates through one value at a time from the list.

4). if column name has `source` then goes to if condition and updates `source values`, else updates `scores values`

5). Finally you can rename the `temp_score` column names or Select required columns from the dataFrame that is being returned

```
def updateValues(testScoresDF: DataFrame, tempScoresDF: DataFrame, cols: List[String]) = {

        val joinDF = testScoresDF.as("test")
          .join(tempScoresDF.as("temp"), Seq("id", "products"), "left")

        val updateValuesDF = cols.foldLeft(joinDF) {
          (df, col) =>
            if (col.contains("source")) {
              df.withColumn(col,
                when($"temp.score1".gt(0) && $"Source1".notEqual("missing"), "FoundOnline")
                  .otherwise($"$col"))
            }
            else {
              df.withColumn("temp_" + col,
                when($"temp.score1".gt(0) && $"Source1".notEqual("missing"), $"temp.$col")
                  .otherwise($"test.$col"))
            }
        }
        updateValuesDF
      }
```